# Laravel mail automation

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I'm developing an invoicing system in order to collect payments from customers. Once I create an invoice, an email including invoice details will be sent to the customers with payment link. I want to re-generate payment token(once it expires) and send renewed payment link to the customers, and want to automate the process.

I created a Job called `renewingInvoiceLinks` and inside the handle method, I wrote code to retrieve all invoices with expired links and create new token and send new link. In `App->Console->Kernel.php` scheduled the job as following. I referred Laravel Docs but did not get the flow properly to dispatch the Job.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new renewingInvoiceLinks, 'renewingInvoiceLinks')->daily();
}
```

Things I want to get clear.

1. Whether using Job to do the requirement is correct or not? If not what is the perfect way to do it.
2. How to dispatch the Job? (Where I need to call the dispatch method?)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is quite subjective and opinionated, but here is how I'd do it:

1. Whenever the payment link is updated, I would fire a custom `PaymentLinkUpdated` event. You can either fire this event in the place(s) where you update the link, or you listen for the `saving` event on the affected model and fire the `PaymentLinkUpdated` event only when the original value is different from the updated one.
2. A custom event listener will listen for the update of payment links and will send out the email containing the payment details and link. This event listener should be [a queued one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#queued-event-listeners) so that emails are sent in the background and do not block the UI.
3. A scheduled job will check for expired payment links and will update the affected records, casting a `PaymentLinkUpdated` event where necessary. This will trigger step 2 (which is automatically queued again).

This way, you'd have all the logic implemented only once and sending mails would not be duplicated. If you have to send a different mail when the payment link is renewed, you can either do so in the event listener or you have to change your strategy entirely.